# Prove Rouché's theorem's geometric explanation

Tags: complex-analysis

Rouché's theorem [states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem) that

> for any two complex-valued functions $f$ and $g$ holomorphic inside
> some region $\displaystyle K$ with closed contour
> $\displaystyle\partial K$, if $|g(z)| < |f(z)|$ on $\displaystyle \partial K$, then
> $f$ and $f + g$ have the same number of zeros inside
> $\displaystyle K$, where each zero is counted as many times as its multiplicity.

Wiki also provides a [Geometric explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem#Geometric_explanation):

> informal way to summarize this argument is as follows: If a person
> were to walk a dog on a leash around and around a tree, such that the
> distance between the person and the tree is always greater than the
> length of the leash, then the person and the dog go around the tree
> the same number of times.

Indeed, here the number of times going around the tree, is exactly the change of arguments of $f$ and $g$, then by [Argument principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle), the original statement on zeros are proved.

However, the geometric explanation itself, though sounds intuitive, how could it be proved? and does it need strict condition such as $f$ and $g$ are both holomorphic, or a weaker condition would do, such as $f(\partial K)$ and $g(\partial K)$ are continuous or rectifiable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The geometric interpretation is, $|f(z)|$ is the distance from the walker to the tree, $|g(z)|$ is the length of the leash, and $f(z) + g(z)$ is the dog's position. The hypothesis $|g(z)| < |f(z)|$, or  $|g(z)/f(z)| < 1$, guarantees that $\phi(z) := 1 + g(z)/f(z)$ lies in the open right half plane, so does not wind about $0$. Logarithmically differentiating $f + g = \phi f$ gives
$$
\frac{(f + g)'(z)}{(f + g)(z)} = \frac{\phi'(z)}{\phi(z)} + \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}.
$$
Integrating over the contour $\partial K$ implies $f + g$ winds around $0$ the same number of times as $f$ along $\partial K$.

You need "holomorphic" to deduce that the number of zeros enclosed by $\partial K$ (i.e., in the interior of $K$) is equal to the winding number of function values about $0$ as $z$ traces $\partial K$ (and particularly, that $f$ and $f + g$ have only finitely many $0$s inside $K$).